# nested if statements based on values in an array

Tags: python

I try to check the several modules of a numbers based on values of an array.

```
 array = [1,2,3,4,5]
 number = 10
```

now I want to do automate the following:

```
if 10%1 ==0:
    if 10%2 == 0:
        if 10%3 == 0:
            if 10%4 == 0:
                if 10%5 ==0:
                     print "10 is dividable by all numbers in the array"
```

I want to make the number of nested if statements based on the length of the array and get the number to check if 10 is dividable out of the array. Is there a way to do this with for loops?

Thanks.

Comment: use the `all` function: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use  `all`:

```
array = [1,2,3,4,5]
number = 10
if all(number % x == 0 for x in array):
    print "%s is dividable by %s" % (str(number), str(array))
```